# Basic decrypter malfunction

Tags: python-3.x

I input ffdsaadj dsaadmaasdadsn ym adsadahaca which should return hi my name jeff but instead is just reverses the string and gets rid of the 'aca'. I don't know why the replace function wont work. Also I'm new to coding so I know its not very optimized

```
a = input('what word do u wanna decrypt ')
def decrypt(word):
    dicti = {
        'a' : 'aasdads',
        'e' : 'dsaad',
        'i' : 'adsada',
        'o' : 'sasada',
        'u' : 'dssajsia'
    }
    word = word.lower()[::-1]
    for vowel in 'aeiou':
        y = dicti.get(vowel)
        word = word.replace(y, vowel)
        print(word)
    word = word[3:]
    print(word)
decrypt(a)
```

Comment: It looks like you need to revert ``word`` *after* the loop, not *before* it. But without knowing what algorithm your decryption is supposed to use, that was just trial and error. Can you clarify *why* you expect your function to give the expected output for the given input?

Comment: I have no clue why that works but it does so thanks